# Printing prop works but printing prop object value does not work

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

i am having really hard time understanding why my code is not working. Could someone please explain to me why i can print the prop object but not access its values?

Parent:

```
function createCarBlocks(){
    return carsJSONData.map((car) => {
        console.log(car);
        return <CarBlock carBlockItem={car}/>
    })
};
```

Child:

```
export interface CarBlockItemProps {
id: string,
modelName: string,
bodyType: string,
modelType: string,
imageUrl: string
```

}

```
const CarBlock = (props: CarBlockItemProps) => {
    console.log("This is me printing props", props);
    console.log("This is me trying to access its value", props.bodyType); //Note i cannot write props.carBlockItem

    return (
        <p>test</p>
    );
};

export default CarBlock;
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Looks like you mean to pass in the properties of `car` rather than pass `car` directly. You could pass them individually (e.g. `<CarBlock id={car.id} modelName={car.modelName}  />` etc) or use the spreading operator (`<CarBlock {...car}/>`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `createCarBlocks()`, function you're returning `CarBlock` components with the prop `carBlockItem` which isn't specified in the `CarBlock` component.

If you want to receive the `carBlockItem` as an object, you could create a new interface that specifies the properties for the item, separate from the interface for the `CarBlock` props

```
export interface CarBlockItem {
    id: string,
    modelName: string,
    bodyType: string,
    modelType: string,
    imageUrl: string
}

export interface CarBlockItemProps {
    carBlockItem: CarBlockItem;
}
```

And destructure the props object in order to get the `carBlockItem` object

```
const CarBlock = ({ carBlockItem }: CarBlockItemProps) => {
    console.log("carBlockItem: ", carBlockItem);
    console.log("This is me trying to access its value", carBlockItem.bodyType); 

    return (
        <p>test</p>
    );
};

export default CarBlock;
```